# Check like status of another page in Page Tab Facebook

Tags: php, facebook

I am curious as to how I can check whether a user is a fan of a different page for like-gating content between two pages in a Page Tab. I currently have it working with an FQL query for off of Facebook, but when using a signed request in the Page Tab, I believe I can only check whether the current page is liked. Is it possible to use an FQL query on a Page Tab, I end up with a blank page if I try to load the page in a Page Tab but it works fine if I load the actual page as opposed to the page tab? Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use user_likes permission to get all likes from a user. But you are not allowed to use that for user-gating. So no it is not possible

Comment: Thanks for the response, from my understanding of what I've read, the only way to like-gate any page is in a Page Tab using the signed request and accessing user_likes needs approval from Facebook which will not grant approval for this use, right?

Comment: Yes that is what I said